# Sampling function produces same result everytime

Tags: java, random

I am generating weighted random numbers(sampling with replacement) through the following code

```
    Object[] population = { 0, 1 };
    double[] weights = { p1, p2 };
    Sampling randsamp = new Sampling(population, weights);
    X = (Integer) randsamp.next();
```

I have tried different values of p1 and p2 which are the probabilities and 0 and 1 are the population(numbers which are to be generated based on p1 and p2).
However, running the code multiple times produces the same result, for example if I make 10 iterations and store the result in an array X[] I get the same array every time the code is executes. Can someone tell me why is this happening? Should I not get different array/numbers at each iteration?

Thanks

Comment: What is `Sampling`?  Is it from some standard library?

Comment: yes it is under jpsgcs.alun.random.Sampling library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search in google `jpsgcs.alun.random.Sampling`, you get some broken links about this `Sampling` class. Moreover, if you browse [here](http://balance.med.utah.edu/wiki/index.php/JPSGCS) you can see that in the jar, that you can download, there is no more even such a package like `random`. So, probably that was removed for some reasons ... Maybe this Sampling class was removed because not working properly? I can just suggest you to get in touch with somebody that wrote this library.

Comment: Thanks! I saw the link does not exist, do you know of any library in Java which cane perform weighted random sampling in Java?

Comment: No, I don't, but I think there are million in internet... Good luck!